# How can I escape commas in a CSV file?

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, libreoffice, openoffice, openoffice-calc

I thought there were two ways to do this: either enclose the field containing the comma in quotes, or place a backslash before the comma. However neither of these is working; when I load up the CSV file into OpenOffice Calc, LibreOffice Calc, or Microsoft Excel, the comma is treated like a field delimiter and my field is split in two, breaking the layout. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a sample of your data that is not being imported as you expect.

Comment: To create a .csv file, I ususally edit it in Notepad or Notepad Plus.

Comment: What does this mean *when I load up the CSV file...*?  There are various ways to do that.  Have you checked the content of the CSV file in a text editor (Notepad or Notepad++)? Post a text example of what that looks like.  Do you have the `TextQualifier` properly set in your viewing program?

Comment: Last week, I posted an answer to a similar question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62765982/field-and-text-delimiters-within-cells-in-csv-files/62767040#62767040.

Answer (score 1):

Try authoring the data in Calc or Excel and then save/export it as CSV. What does it produce when you view the CSV in a plaintext editor?

In my testing with Excel, I see it encloses the field with the comma in double quotes and correctly interprets it when I re-epen it.

When you edit the data in a plaintext editor, make sure you're using regular double quotes (`"`) and not so-called smart quotes (`“”`).